# Turn off Touch bar Preview on display

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, touch-bar

[image]
I do not see this on other Macbooks. Not sure how I got it, but I cannot find any settings in the Preferences.

Basically, every time I touch the touch bar, I get a preview of the touchbar as a strip on the the bottom of the screen display. Long Press is delayed as a result of this as there is a circle progress that shows to help users in long pressing.

How can I disable this? It is intrusive and not useful at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Zoom. Uncheck Show Touch bar zoom (not sure what exactly it says, not on my computer right now).

As of 10.12.3, there is a bug. If that checkbox didn't appear, restart your computer will make it appear.

Comment: It's wierd that when I search touch bar in System Preferences, it doesn't point anything to Accessibility.

Comment: @NeilDA yeah, I know. It's kind of hidden

Comment: It says `Enable Touch Bar Zoom`.